# Size textView with weights in LinearLayout

Tags: android, textview, android-layout-weight

I have an horizontal LinearLayout with: ImageView / TextView / ImageView.

I have distribuited these items with weights at this form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/vboxrow_icono"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/viewboxrow_icon_height"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/viewboxrow_icon_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/viewboxrow_icon_margin"
        android:layout_weight="0.1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vboxrow_texto"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="@dimen/viewbox_desc_size"
        android:text="Title"
        android:layout_weight="0.85" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/vboxrow_favorito"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/viewboxrow_icon_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/viewboxrow_icon_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/icono_listado_nofavorito"
        android:layout_weight="0.05" />

</LinearLayout>
```

All works very well, but when the text is very large the image is not at the end  because in his place it is the text. I don't know why it occurs if I have put weight for this image ... How can I delimit the text if it is very large? E.g. with 3 points or in other line because I have put 'wrap_content' for height in TextView.

Both cases:

1) normal text: ImageView / Text View / Image View

2) large text:  ImageView / Text Vieeeeeeeeeeeeew

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're giving a .85 weight to the text view, so it will hog all the space.

Comment: Since the TextView is added before the second ImageView it has priority over the latter and is allowed to push it if necessary.  You may have to set a fixed width in dp for the text view and supply a maxlines or ellipsis options for it.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to achieve, using a RelativeLayout might be better. You anchor both ImageView on either the left or right side of the RelativeLayout, and then put a text with width = match_parent that is at the right of the first image, and at the left of the second one.

Comment: @Gary Bak I can't put a fixed width in dp for the text view because I want that it is in most of the screen and depends of device it has more or less dpi

Comment: @jujux789 I had my layout as you say before, but I can't do that because I want to have the same aspect in all devices ... due to this reason I have put a LinearLayout with weights.

Answer (score 0):

You always have the option of sizing the components within the code, this will give you the percentages you are looking for but able to fix the width of the TextView.  I would probably use the suggestion from @jujux789 and use a RelativeLayout or some other custom component.

```
    ImageView iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
    ImageView iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);
    TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;

    float width1 = dpWidth * 0.1f;
    float width2 = dpWidth * 0.85f;
    float width3 = dpWidth * 0.5f;

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp1 = iv1.getLayoutParams();
    lp1.width = (int)width1;
    iv1.setLayoutParams(lp1);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp2 = tv1.getLayoutParams();
    lp2.width = (int)width2;
    tv1.setLayoutParams(lp2);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp3 = iv2.getLayoutParams();
    lp3.width = (int)width3;
    iv2.setLayoutParams(lp3);
```